# how i can show splited (image or plot) of in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```py
def split(img, nbxsplit, nbysplit): # this is for number of splitting in line and column
   xpart = int(img.shape[0] / nbxsplit) # number of part or region in line shape of image
   ypart = int(img.shape[1] / nbysplit) # number of part in column shape of image
   arr = [] # empty arr for storage
   for i in range(0, img.shape[0]-xpart+1, xpart): # boucle stepping by part of x and end until she arrived the last part ,in the there will be lost of of little size beacause sometimes thelast part we can't devide it into flly part
      for j in range(0, img.shape[1]-ypart+1, ypart):
         arr.append(img[i:i+xpart,j:j+ypart])
   a = np.array(arr)
   a = np.reshape(a, (nbxsplit,nbysplit))
   return a
```

i want to split images to 4 region so i will initialize nbxsplit=2 and nbysplit=2
how i can show image splitted with just plt.imshow()

i try this but it throw to error

```py
plt.bar((values.shape), values)
```

and i try this also and throw to error

```py
plt.bar(values, color='maroon', width=0.4)
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling split(). What input args? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: when i try imshow   he show a white blank image ,                                                        ---> 10                                plt.bar((values.shape), values)                                   --> 420     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    421     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    422     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: nbxsplit=2
nbysplit=2
spl_images=split(img,nbxsplit,nbysplit)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
for i in range(nbysplit*nbxsplit):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(spl_images[i])